# Create wizard some clarification

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I want to create simple wizard with 3 pages

1. Page 1 have just next button
2. Page 2 have next and previous
3. Page 3 have previous and finish

I have created the pages and add to them needed buttons and in the events I have call to the next pages, for instance in page one in the button click I added the following code

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    p2 = new Page2();
    NavigationService.Navigate(p2);
}
```

In the main window cs I have changed the inheritance to `NavigationWindow` instead of `Window` and in the xaml also. Currently its working but I have 3 questions.

1. The pages which displayed is part of the main window, how can i avoid it, since when I run it the buttons place is not like I put in the designer? It was changed.
2. The button currently in the Grid, should I put them in different control (the button place should be like any wizard in the left buttom of the page) ?
3. How can I avoid the navigation arrows in the page right upper screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questsions in reverse,

*3. How can I avoid the navigation arrows in the page upper right screen?*

I have an opensource library http://winchrome.codeplex.com/ that re-styles navigation windows in several ways. For example these are all `NavigationWindow` s

[image: example NavigationWindow s]

In short you just style the `NavigationWindow` to only show the parts you want.

*2.The button currently in the Grid, should I put them in different control (the button place should be like any wizard in the left buttom of the page) ?*

If you look at the styles from [WinChrome](http://winchrome.codeplex.com/) then you will see that it is just a case of rebuiliding the UI as you want and providing a `ContentPresenter` to hold your pages. e.g. the [VS2012 style](http://winchrome.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinChrome/UI/VS2012Window.xaml) applies lots of styles on the window but avoids adding back and forward buttons., whereas the [Win7 style](http://winchrome.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinChrome/UI/Win7NavigationWindow.xaml) rebuilds the back and forwards in a Win7 Style.

If you do this however you will need a means of passing your enabled or visible states to the buttons outside the pages. Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8197/Designer-centric-Wizard-control for how to do this in Winforms. In WPF you could either derive from your `Page`s to create `WizardPage` classes with `CanBack`, `CanNext` or `IsFinish` properties, or alteratively define attached properties to do the same (There are examples of how to do this in [VS2012.cs](http://winchrome.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinChrome/VS2012.cs) where we define the glow color)

And finally

*1. The pages which displayed is part of the main window, how can i avoid it, since when I run it the buttons place is not like I put in the designer? It was changed.*

I'd need to see some code to comment on how you've done it, but if you look at any of the demo programs in [WinChrome](http://winchrome.codeplex.com/) then you can see how I've done it without problems.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks!,this is free? this is the code of the window         public MainWindow()
            {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Content = new Page1();
            }

Comment: and this is the xaml - <NavigationWindow x:Class="WPFWizardTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500">

</NavigationWindow>

Comment: maybe you have idea how can I start from the page withot the page inside the window..

Comment: If you don't have a `Page` inside the window, what do you want in there?

Comment: Yes, It's on an MIT licence so basically use it as you see fit. Full details http://winchrome.codeplex.com/license